# substrate template node build error

Tags: substrate-node-template

I'm having trouble running the nodes.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

link: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

command:

```
./scripts/docker_run.sh
```

error:

```
*** Start Substrate node template ***
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Network substrate-node-template_default  Removed                                                                                                  0.1s
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Network substrate-node-template_default  Created                                                                                                  0.1s
[+] Running 7/7
 ⠿ dev Pulled                                                                                                                                      100.6s
   ⠿ d121f8d1c412 Pull complete                                                                                                                     32.3s
   ⠿ 1b985895e9b7 Pull complete                                                                                                                     32.3s
   ⠿ 809a473c961b Pull complete                                                                                                                     32.4s
   ⠿ 89f7c794c3df Pull complete                                                                                                                     33.7s
   ⠿ ea120af1c111 Pull complete                                                                                                                     42.7s
   ⠿ de2c35bb8bf1 Pull complete                                                                                                                     96.2s
error: failed to parse manifest at `/var/www/node-template/node/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  failed to parse the `edition` key

Caused by:
  this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
```

my env:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b 2022-07-16)
cargo 1.62.1 (a748cf5a3 2022-06-08)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose.yml` file in the root directory seems to be using an outdated Docker image that has an old version of Rust. Replace the following line in that file:

```yml
image: paritytech/ci-linux:974ba3ac-20201006
```

with:

```yml
image: paritytech/ci-linux:42a94a57-20220730
```

and try running `./scripts/docker_run.sh` again. It should build and start fine.

You can also use the following for the latest version always:

```yml
image: paritytech/ci-linux:production
```

Rest of the tags for the image are [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/paritytech/ci-linux/tags). And [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/236) is the related issue in the repo.